# Foreign Keys won't cascade in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I can't seem to get my cascade action going here. I've got two tables defined as the following.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? An update to system_rigs "id" won't cascade to the messages table.

### Messages Table

```
CREATE TABLE `edr_messages` (  
  `message_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `rig_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `message` text,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`,`rig_id`),  
  KEY `pkey` (`message_id`),  
  KEY `rig_id` (`rig_id`),  
  CONSTRAINT `edr_messages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rig_id`)
      REFERENCES `system_rigs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

### Rigs Table

```
CREATE TABLE `system_rigs` (  
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: Please note that it's not generally good practice allow primary keys to be updated. That said, this rule isn't *enforced by mysql*, so I don't see why your schema isn't working for you...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, and it worked fine for me (mysql 5.1.41). Maybe we're not clear on what should happen, so let me show you what I tried... I ran your `create table` clauses (in reverse order). Then I ran the following test:

```
insert into system_rigs (name) values('computron');
```

> **system_rigs**
> id: 13
> name: computron

```
insert into edr_messages (rig_id, message) values (13, 'here\'s a message');
```

> **edr_messages**
> id: 2
> rig_id: 13
> message: here's a message

```
update system_rigs set id = 26 where id = 13;
```

> **system_rigs**
> id: 26
> name: computron
>
> **edr_messages**
> id: 2
> rig_id: 26
> message: here's a message